# Trigger: move deleted rows to archive table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, delete, plpgsql

I have a small (~10 rows) table called `restrictions` in my PostgreSQL database, where values are deleted and inserted on a daily basis.

I would like to have a table called `restrictions_deleted`, where every row that is deleted from `restrictions` will be stored automatically. Since `restrictions` has a serial id, there will be no duplicates.

How do I write such a trigger in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to move the old data into the `restrictions_deleted` table before it gets deleted. This is done with the [`OLD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html) data type. You can use a regulat `INSERT` statement and and use the `OLD` values as the values-to-be-inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER moveDeleted
BEFORE DELETE ON restrictions 
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE moveDeleted();


CREATE FUNCTION moveDeleted() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO restrictions_deleted VALUES(OLD.column1, OLD.column2,...);
       RETURN OLD;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You can replace the explicit list of column values with something like `VALUES((OLD).*)`

Comment: Works fine, but the `create function` needs to be called before `create trigger`. And the `VALUES((OLD).*)` trick suggested by KayEss is nice.

Answer (score 8):

If you are open to a different approach, Have you considered adding a 'deleted' Boolean flag to the table, or a 'deleted_at' timestamp instead.

Or better still, deny CRUD access to your database tables and handle the audit trail in your transactional API :)

Comment: This will cause performance issues when deleted record count is too large (millions)